# Are Pandas nullable Integer types bad for performance compared to float

Tags: python, pandas, performance, data-cleaning

I am new to Data Science, I was trying to do some data cleaning and I had a column of Years in my data frame. Supposedly a year should be an integer, but as far as there are some NA values it automatically is denoted as float. I wonder if it is better to convert it to nullable int like `pd.Int32Dtype()` or leave it float. Is there any difference in terms of performance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I constructed two basic examples, both with the same data. I created a `DataFrame` from a 1-dimensional array with a size of 500,000. I also assigned `None` to a few members of the array.

Data construction:

```
import time
import pandas as pd

years = [i for i in range(0, 500000)]
years[23] = None
years[44] = None
years[151] = None
```

**Int:**

```
start = time.perf_counter()

df_int = pd.DataFrame(data = years, dtype = pd.Int32Dtype())

finish = time.perf_counter()
print(f'Finished in {finish-start}')


# Finished in 0.17838970199999993
```

**Float:**

```
start = time.perf_counter()

df_float = pd.DataFrame(data = years)

finish = time.perf_counter()
print(f'Finished in {finish-start}')


# Finished in 0.07671123900000004
```

From the output, converting the data to `pd.Int32Dtype()` is apparently slower.

However, the time it took to represent this array of 500,000 members to `Int32Dtype` was still very fast for a large array. This is a very basic example, as real-world data will have many more columns, nested arrays, etc. This is especially true for data science as machine learning datasets can be extremely large and multi-dimensional.

**EDIT:**

Because you are working with missing values, you will most likely be making use of methods that, well, deal with missing values in your data.

I set up a script that averages the time taken to remove the missing values and reset the index of the data frame. The averaging was done using the times from 200 runs. The array size is still the same as before: 500,000. What is different this time is that I made every value that is evenly divisble by 200 `None`. This means that there are 2500 appearances of `None` in this array.

```
years = [None if i%200 == 0 else i for i in range(0, 500000)]
```

**Int:**

```
times = []
for i in range(0,200):
    df_int = pd.DataFrame(data = years, dtype = pd.Int32Dtype(), columns=['years'])

    start = time.perf_counter()
    df_int.dropna(inplace=True)
    df_int.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
    finish = time.perf_counter()

    times.append((finish-start))
```

**Float:**

```
times = []
for i in range(0,200):
    df_float = pd.DataFrame(data = years, columns=['years'])

    start = time.perf_counter()
    df_float.dropna(inplace=True)
    df_float.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
    finish = time.perf_counter()

    times.append((finish-start))
```

Averages were taken like so:

```
avg = sum(times)/len(times)
```

Outputs were as follows:

```
# Float: 0.009853112889999979
# Int:   0.009194320404999973
```

Resources:

[Working with missing data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/missing_data.html)

[Nullable integer data type](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html#integer-na)

[pandas.DataFrame.fillna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html#pandas.DataFrame.fillna)

Comment: thanks for your answer, although it was good to know that the conversion to float is faster my problem was a little bit different. while loading the dataset the column already had the float type, and I was wondering if the data type affects the performance. more specifically is there any difference doing calculations on pd.Int32Dtype() compared with float?